BRep Reference Error with Parts Created Using Adaptive Sweep
I have a function called CreateOffsetSurfaces that I use to create extracts from selected faces.
It works fine with data created using the Step and Sweep commands, but I get an error when I run it on parts created using the Adaptive Sweep command. You can see the error in the image attached as Error 1.
For example, a working BRep:
RSur:(Face:(Brp:(ThickSurface.3;2:(Brp:(GSMSweep.1;(Brp:(GSMLineCorner.1;(Brp:(GSMPoint.33;1);Brp:(GSMPoint.35;1)))))));None:();Cf14:());WithPermanentBody;WithoutBuildError;WithSelectingFeatureSupport;MFBRepVersion_CXR29)

A non-working BRep:
RSur:(Face:(Brp:(ThickSurface.10;2:(Brp:(GSMSweepSketch.7;(Brp:(GSMLineCorner.12;(Brp:(GSMPoint.128);Brp:(GSMPoint.130)));Brp:(Sketch.12;1);Brp:(Sketch.9;1)))));None:();Cf14:());WithPermanentBody;WithoutBuildError;WithSelectingFeatureSupport;MFBRepVersion_CXR29)

I believe this error is due to the BRep name not being correct. Could you please help me understand how to write a BRep function that would prevent this error?
Thank you!
Error 1

' Belirli bir geometrik eleman için BRep adýný oluþturma iþlevi
Public Function GetBrep(MyBRepName As String) As String
    ' Ýsimden "Selection_" önekini kaldýr
    MyBRepName = Replace(MyBRepName, "Selection_", "")
    ' Ýsimdeki kapanýþ parantezinden önceki kýsmý al
    MyBRepName = Left(MyBRepName, InStrRev(MyBRepName, "));"))
    ' BRep referansý için gerekli parametreleri ekle
    MyBRepName = MyBRepName & ");WithPermanentBody;WithoutBuildError;WithSelectingFeatureSupport;MFBRepVersion_CXR29)"
    ' Oluþturulan BRep adýný döndür
    GetBrep = MyBRepName
End Function

Function CreateOffsetSurfaces(selectedFaces As collection, hybridBody
As hybridBody, nonTangentFaces As collection) As collection
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim part As part
Set part = CATIA.ActiveDocument.part

Dim hybridShapeFactory As hybridShapeFactory
Set hybridShapeFactory = part.hybridShapeFactory

Dim extractSurfaces As New collection
Dim i As Integer

' Log dosyasini C:\Users\Public dizinine kaydet
Dim logFilePath As String
logFilePath = "C:\Users\Public\BrepNamesLog.txt"

Dim logFile As Object
Set logFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(logFilePath,8, True)

For i = 1 To selectedFaces.count
    Dim face As face
    Set face = selectedFaces(i)

    ' BRep ismini al ve log dosyasina yaz
    Dim brepName As String
    brepName = GetBrep(face.Name)
    logFile.WriteLine brepName

    Dim reference1 As reference
    Set reference1 = part.CreateReferenceFromBRepName(brepName, face.Parent)

    If Not reference1 Is Nothing Then
        Dim hybridShapeExtract1 As HybridShapeExtract
        Set hybridShapeExtract1 = hybridShapeFactory.AddNewExtract(reference1)
        hybridShapeExtract1.PropagationType = 3
        hybridShapeExtract1.ComplementaryExtract = False
        hybridShapeExtract1.IsFederated = False
        hybridShapeExtract1.Name = "Hoseoffset_" & i

        hybridBody.AppendHybridShape hybridShapeExtract1
        extractSurfaces.Add hybridShapeExtract1

        ' Tanjant kontrolüne göre renk atama
        If IsObjectInCollection(face, nonTangentFaces) Then
            HighlightFace hybridShapeExtract1, "Red"
        Else
            HighlightFace hybridShapeExtract1, "Green"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Could not create reference for one of the selected faces.", vbExclamation
    End If
Next i

' Log dosyasini kapat
logFile.Close

Set CreateOffsetSurfaces = extractSurfaces
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "An error occurred while creating extract surfaces: " & Err.Description, vbCritical

' Hata durumunda log dosyasini kapat
If Not logFile Is Nothing Then
    logFile.Close
End If End Function



Which line throws that error? You may check via a macro record the correct BREP of this face (and compare with your per macro generated string).

In my short test, a recorded macro creates the same error after executing. So I guess this BREP is wrong.
